# GLFW mouselook under OSX

Tags: opengl, mouse, glfw

I'm continuing to port an OpenGL app from Visual Studio 2012 to XCode 5.

The only major issue I'm having is mouselook. It "doesn't work" under OSX (Mavericks).

Here's the (pseudocode):

Pre-update, executed at the start of the frame:

```
void Dispatcher::PreUpdate(GameTime &time)
{
    m_currentKeyboardState = m_nextKeyboardState;
    m_previousMousePosition = m_currentMousePosition;

    GetMousePosition(m_currentMousePosition);
}
```

Post-update, executed, well, after input processing, at the end of the frame:

```
void Dispatcher::PostUpdate(GameTime &time)
{
    m_previousKeyboardState = m_currentKeyboardState;

    if (m_captureMouse)
        RecenterMouse();
}
```

Method to recenter the mouse:

```
void Dispatcher::RecenterMouse()
{
    glfwSetCursorPos(m_window, m_windowSize.x / 2.f, m_windowSize.y / 2.f);

    GetMousePosition(m_currentMousePosition);

    if (m_previousMousePosition != m_currentMousePosition)
        cout << "Mouse: " << m_currentMousePosition.x << "," << m_currentMousePosition.y << endl;

    m_previousMousePosition = m_currentMousePosition;
}
```

And, jut for completeness:

```
void Dispatcher::GetMouseMotion(Vector2 &movedBy)
{
    if(m_captureMouse)
    {
        movedBy.x = (m_currentMousePosition.x - m_previousMousePosition.x);
        movedBy.y = (m_currentMousePosition.y - m_previousMousePosition.y);
    }
    else
    {
        movedBy.x=movedBy.y=0;
    }
}
```

If `m_captureMouse` is `true`, and `m_previousMousePosition != m_currentMousePosition`, the y delta is always 1, no matter how far I've moved the mouse. (Actually, using the trackpad, but should be indentical.)

This code works perfectly under Win7, but never returns anything other motion than `(0,1)` under OSX.

Suggestions? I've seen other questions regarding glfw and osx, but no solutions.

**EDIT**

It's worth noting if I turn off mouse capture (which basically does everything *but* recenter the mouse at the end of the frame), mouselook works correctly but, of course, the cursor is free to wander outside of the window, which doesn't really work for a first-person app.

Comment: I've run into this problem before, and fixed it by changing `setCursorInputMode` from Hidden to Disabled.

Comment: @Mokosha perfect! Thanks. If you change this to an answer, I'll accept. (I haven't found anything that was really a duplicate.) I wonder why this is different between OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually solved by changing `glfwSetInputMode` with `GLFW_CURSOR` from `GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN` to `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED`.

The behavior differences are due to the differences in OS APIs that GLFW uses and how they interact with the windowing system. In the [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gaa92336e173da9c8834558b54ee80563b), it says that `DISABLED` should be used for 3D camera controls, and `HIDDEN` should be used when rendering a custom cursor.